# GIT Rebase issue

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I am new to Gitlab. We use Local branch to code and then push our changes to Gitlab and then later it's merged from the UI. So the problem is :
I created a new branch. Did some work on it and then committed and pushed a piece of code (It's not yet merged yet).
Now I want to commit another change on top of it. But the problem is there has been work done on the files after my first push so I want to rebase the branch and then do the new changes on top of it. But when I try to rebase it shows the changes from my last commit as new files. What do I do in this case ?

The flow should be.. My committed changes--> someone else's work --> My new changes on top of it.

Can you please help ?

Comment: So if i get it right u want the changes of your colleague to? SO you can just pull the branch and then push it with ur changes. Or didn't I get ur question correctly?

Comment: Yes, But when I am doing a git pull --rebase . Then the changes from my previous commit are showing as. -->   
**Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
 new file:   main.py**

What do I do with these ? Shall I just commit these file again ?

Comment: Then commit it again. It might be that ur colleague didnt apply your previous changes to his commit, meaning your previous changes are like new changes. --> Push again

Comment: Why did you use rebase flag along with the git pull command?

I think you should have done a simple pull from your colleague's branch, then resolve the merge conflicts (if any), then commit your new changes and finally push the commits.